# How to clear a List view items

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have created a listview items with a button to add items but pressing,
is there any function that I can use to remove elements on the list?
for example a button next to the add button and clear the list.

Comment: Could you please explain what you want removed, do you want to remove the whole list or just a single item?

Comment: you can clear a list using yourList.clear() in setstate;

Comment: Consider including [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better answer

Comment: I think he wants to remove single items as well as clear the list

Answer (score 1):

Just call method `.clear(`) in variable you store list.

```
final list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
// somewhere in your function
list.clear();
```

You can see many other method to remove elements in a list depends on your scenario such as

```
list.removeAt(index)
list.removeLast()
list.removeRange(start, end)
list.removeWhere((element) => false)
```

But I'm not sure about your question because it's very simple answer. Is this really what you want?